# How to convert javascript import statement using babel or any other tool

Tags: ecmascript-6, requirejs, babeljs

I am new to this ES6. So, I have difficulty like below:

I wrote class `TopoPlaneClass.js`:

```js
export default class TopoPlaneClass {

}
```

And importing `{TopoPlaneClass}` to `3D.js` file like below

```
import {TopoPlaneClass} from "./topo/TopoPlaneClass.js";
```

like `TopoPlaneClass.js` file I have many files.

To compile it I am using like: `npm run build`

`package.json` file:

```
"scripts": {    
    "build": "babel ./src/source -d compiled"
    
},

"scripts": {
    "build": "babel --presets es2015 src/source -d compiled"
},
```

So that class will compiled and stored in compiled folder.

But `3D.js` file is like below, and **while loading the this file to browser giving error for require(...)**

```
var _TopoPlaneClass = require("./topo/TopoPlaneClass.js");
```

Here I am not clear how to do (how to convert file so that require function will be available or dependency resolved)?

Comment: You can remove the auto compilation part from this and make it a separate question. Also, I suggest removing the body of the `TopoPlaneClass` as it's not related and will make it easier to read.

Comment: Yes, updated thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### TL;DR

Babel only translates the `import` syntax into some other syntax like the CommonJS `require` in your case. The most common tools used to make that `require` call work in browsers, at the time of writing this answer, are bundlers like [webpack](https://webpack.js.org/), [parcel](https://parceljs.org/) etc.

### Modern Browsers

Import declarations are part of the language standard. In the browser they can be used in scripts that were included through a `<script>` tag with the `type` attribute set to `"module"` like this:

```
<script type="module" src="3d.js"></script>
```

You can see [here](https://caniuse.com/#feat=es6-module) which modern browsers currently support this. Keep reading for the browsers that don't.

### Transpiling syntax

To keep writing your code with the new import syntax, but have it converted to one of the solutions that were used to simulate modules in JavaScript before ES modules existed, you will have to tell babel which format to use. By default, the `es2015` preset will convert to what is known as CommonJS format resulting in that `require` call. Using the `env` preset (which is also recommended instead of `es2015`), you can change the outputted module format from the [modules field](https://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/preset-env/#modules).

You install the preset with

```
npm install babel-preset-env
```

and create a `.babelrc` file in the root of your project with this content like this:

```
{
  "presets": [["env", { "modules": "commonjs" }]]
}
```

(you must also remove the `--presets es2015` in package.json after this)

### Modules before ESM

The next step depends on the chosen solution. If, for example, you chose `amd`, you will have to include a module loader like [requirejs](http://requirejs.org/). If you stick with CommonJS, a very common solution to make it work in a browser is to then bundle your code with a bundler like webpack.

Modern bundlers do much more than just make the require call work in browsers. It might require some work to setup, and will also change how you apply babel. [Browserify](http://browserify.org/) is an exception, as it only focuses on this one thing and doesn't change your workflow that much. You will have to consider the trade-offs of each before choosing which one to use.

Comment: good ! I understood something but not much clear. if you have any blog or link to read which can give me clear idea. I need to get some more knowledge over it.

Comment: @PatelHardik [this](https://github.com/verekia/js-stack-from-scratch) has all the tools you need to setup a modern js stack. You won't need everything in there, but it's nice to have everything in one place and you can read more about each tool as need arises.